# Connecting from google cloud run to google cloud (mysql) using .net core

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I have a .net core app installed as a docker on google cloud run, this app that needs to be connected to cloud sql (mysql).

When using the private ip address it, it's not working.
When using public IP, it's working, but It's not a good solution for production.

this is my connection string:

```
"ConnectionString": "server=10.4.16.6;database=mydb;user=root;pwd=mypwd"
```

When I create the app, Im able to select the database i need to connect to:

[image]

But this is not helping to connect.
[The relevant docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run?_ga=2.34227361.-1029630182.1572103622&_gac=1.113345141.1573491790.CjwKCAiAwZTuBRAYEiwAcr67OUP3fp41ZJhxuVRqaoHRPSTL7k9P6vOUShiMg7sltb_8YsZFuhjTcBoCw_gQAvD_BwE) are explaining how to do it for python and java explictly.

Comment: You cannot connect using IP addresses. Cloud Run does not support VPC, yet. How do you expect 10.4.16.6 IP address to resolve? The docs you linked clearly say you need to use `PROJECT-ID:REGION:INSTANCE-ID` as the connection string.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google - Is this way supported in .net core? how do I change my connection string to support this? with user, pass and db name.thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use public IP then you would need to rely on service account to connect to Cloud SQL. However, .net MySQL driver has no understanding of GCP IAM and Service accounts. So you will need to use a proxy called `Cloud SQL Proxy`. Cloud SQL Proxy understands IAM and Service accounts.

The flow will basically look like this:

> Your app -> Regular MySQL Port -> Cloud SQL Proxy(Installed in the
>   app's network or locally) -> CloudSQL

You will need to do the following:

1. Create a service account
2. Assign the role of `Cloud SQL Client` to the created service account
3. Download the service account key in the json format
4. Set env variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\Downloaded.json`
5. Download [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy_x64.exe)
6. Run it `cloud_sql_proxy -instances=projectname:regioname:instanceid=tcp:3306
7. At this point you MySQL proxy ready to accept connections at 3306, modify the connection string to take `localhost` or wherever you installed the Cloud SQL Proxy.

Learn more at [About the Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy)

Answer (score 1):

You can create the Cloud Run app from the console (and select the Cloud SQL Connection) or from the `gcloud` command line and specify

```
--add-cloudsql-instances <INSTANCE-NAME> --set-env-vars INSTANCE-CONNECTION-NAME="INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"
```

These settings automatically enable and configures the Cloud SQL proxy.  You can connect to the proxy, from your asp.net Core app, using the unix domain socket using the format: `/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME`.

I used the following connection string in my `appsettings.json` and it worked for me:

> "Server=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME;Database=DB_NAME;Uid=USER_NAME;Pwd=PASSWORD;Protocol=unix"

NB.  Make sure you have given the service account that your Cloud Run app is running under Cloud SQL Client role in IAM